# Dividing multipart polygon into many polygons using QGIS

Tags: qgis, multipart, singlepart

I have a polygon which is actually composed of many polygons but it results as unique geometry in the shapefile. It's easier to explain with a picture. The yellow parts are in my shapefile a single polygon.
I want to make each part be a different polygon with different attributes.

[image]

I tried with "Multiparts to single part" but the result is another layer with only those polygons. I need instead a unique layer.

Comment: Which version you are using? And which function do you use (frrom menu, toolbox or editing mode)?

Comment: I'm using the version 2.18.2 and the function is from vector<geometry<multipart to single part.@OtoKaláb

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your approach is almost correct. `Singleparts to multipart` from vector menu is (from version 2.16) using same tools as in processing toolbox, and as other processing tools from toolbox takes only selected features from input vector data by default. This can be configured in menu `Processing -> Options...`.

So deselect all features in layer, and run it again.

If you don't want create new layer, you can also edit the layer and use `Split selected multi-part features to single part` function from `Digitizing Tools` plugin.

[image]

Comment: I can not see this "Split selected multi-part features to single part", I will try to download the latest version

Comment: Even in the last version I can't find the "Split selected multi-part features to single part" in my Advanced editing toolbar. why? @OtoKaláb

Comment: @Giovanna my bad, it was a mistake :) I edited it, but still the first solution may work.

Answer (score 0):

I have found latest version has this processing tool "Polygon Part to separate polygon" which does the work.